# Filtering through a Django Countries list

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to retrieve a list of tags that share the same `name` as a django Country. (i will be throwing it into my autocomplete search). What I have isn't working:

**View:**

```
from django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES
...

@login_required
def country_tags(request):
    result = {}
    tags = Tags.objects.all()
    countries = list(COUNTRIES)
    for tag in tags:
        for country in countries: 
            if country.name == tag.name:
                result[tag.name] = tag.name.title()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result))
```

Can't quite figure out why this isn't working. Am I wrong to reference `country.name`?

Comment: Yes you are wrong in `country.name`, but that's not really the problem.

Comment: Paste the exception here, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that should work. `COUNTRIES` is a 2-tuple tuple.

```
countries_only = [x[1] for x in COUNTRIES]
tags = Tag.objects.filter(tag.name__in=countries_only)
results = {}
for t in tags:
   results[t.name] = t.name.title()
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTRIES` is just a list of 2 elements tuples - there is no `name` property. You should do something like `country[1] == tag.name`.